# Integration question regarding the measurement of the electric field

Tags: integration, vectors, volume, spheres, angle

**The problem:**

> Find the electric field a distance z from the center of a
>   spherical surface of radius R (see figure) that carries a uniform charge
>   density σ. Treat the case z < R (inside) as well as z > R (outside).
>   Express your answers in terms of the total charge q on the sphere. [Hint:
>   Use the law of cosines to write
>   r
>   in terms of R and θ. Be sure to take
>   the positive square root: √
>   R2 + z
>   2 − 2Rz = (R − z) if R > z, but it is
>   (z − R) if R < z.]

I understood the concept, but I just can't understand one little part in the solution below. They use that $cos \psi = \frac{z-Rcos\theta}{r}$ - why though? Why is it necessary/helpful?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$dq=\sigma R^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$

This is the total charge E. $E_z$ is the component along z-axis, which is at an angle of $\psi$ to the direction of E. Thus, multiplication with $\cos\psi$ is required.

Comment: Tried thinking about it some more and I still don't fully understand it. Why do we need the $E_z$ component? My general equation is $E(r)=kq/r^2$ which translates into $E(r)=k \int \frac{dq}{r^2}$ when integrating. When should the realization come that I need $E_z$?

Comment: You see, there are two components - The z component and the other component perpendicular to z=axis (x-y plane). This other component gets cancelled in a circle (There exists a point complementary to the chosen point. This negates the x-y plane component, leaving only the z-component) Thus, it is neglected. Only Ez is computed

Comment: In the sketch above, $\overrightarrow E_z$ points in the $+z$ direction. Where does $\overrightarrow E$ point? In all directions of the $xyz$ space? I think this might clear up my confusion.

Comment: You are right!. In all directions of $xyz$ space in general, In all directions of $xyz$ plane towards positive $z$ axis in this particular question.